# how can we use redux state in useState to set initial values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to use redux value to set an initial state of react component using useState.when I am trying to set the state of setIsStar it says currentChannelName is null. How can I avoid this? or is there any other way

```
const currentChannel = useSelector(state => state.channel.currentChannel);
const currentChannelName = currentChannel.name;
  
const [isStar, setIsStar] = useState({
    [currentChannelName]: true
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Possible solution is to combine it with `useEffect`:

```
const currentChannel = useSelector(state => state.channel.currentChannel);
const currentChannelName = currentChannel.name;

useEffect(() => {
    if(currentChannelName) {
        setIsStar({[currentChannelName]: true});
    }
}, [currentChannelName]); // listen only to currentChannelName changes

const [isStar, setIsStar] = useState(currentChannelName ? {
    [currentChannelName]: true
}: {});
```

`

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid this as it dilutes your state across two separate domains.

Keep app-wide state in your redux store, keep local component state in your components.

If you really do want to do this, you'll probably just have to deal with the initial case where your component has mounted but the store is not populated with the data you need.

```
const currentChannel = useSelector(state => state.channel.currentChannel);
const currentChannelName = currentChannel.name;

const [isStar, setIsStar] = useState(currentChannelName && {
  [currentChannelName]: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be:

```
// Redux state
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(user.firstName || '');
```

Comment: // Redux state
const flash = useSelector((state) => state.flash);
 useEffect(() => {
        const { is_loading, is_success, is_error, is_finally, items, errors } = flash;
        if (is_loading) {
            console.log("REDUX UPDATE is_loading VALUE " + is_loading);
        } else if (is_success) {
            console.log("REDUX UPDATE is_success VALUE " + is_success);
        }
        else if (is_error) {
            console.log("REDUX UPDATE is_error VALUE " + is_error);
        }
    }, [flash]);